# ~an inevitable if long-resisted final frontier of my musical taste

Tags: word-usage

This is from [*The New York Times* article.](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/06/18/arts/music/dad-rock.html)

> As I sighed and once again dropped the needle on my parents’ old copy
> of “Gaucho,” I started to see that my Steely Dan phase was not an
> aberration, but an inevitable **if** long-resisted final frontier of
> my musical taste.

Is the 'if' in bold a typo of 'of'?

Comment: No it is correct as "if". Using "but" instead of "if" comes fairly close to the meaning.

Comment: @Peter Is 'long-resisted' a verb?

Comment: No, it is an adjective, applying to "frontier". It is a long-resisted frontier because for a long time I resisted it.

Comment: @Peter Thank you very much.

Comment: BTW, I'd use commas around, " if long-resisted".

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thank you very much.